# MySQL 8.0 not being able to create any query plans

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a very simple query:

```sql
explain
select *
from mytable
limit 1
```

And I cannot see the execution plan, I receive this error:

`Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'explain select * from mytable limit 1' at line 1`

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: It's working here (Mysqlworkbench 8.0.28 / MySQL 8.0.28 / Windows)

Comment: In Mysql-workbench you need not type `explain`, Ctrl+Alt+X also explains the current statement.